# Why jQuery version is changed when selecting a different site in Liferay 7 DXP?

Tags: jquery, liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-7

I have a site called "Intranet" that I created from scratch. This site uses a Liferay Theme based on the **baseTheme": "styled"**. I noticed this theme is loading **jQuery "2.1.4"**.

However, after login into my portal, I am being redirected to the **"Default System Site"** that comes with Liferay out-of-the-box; this site is changing the **jQuery version to "1.11.3"**.

Previous change causes my initial jQuery object doesn't have some plugins (like ***Twitter Bootstrap's modal $.fn.modal***), since they were loaded at the very beginning in the **jQuery 2.1.4** window object.

I was investigating where Bootstrap is loaded and I realized there is one JSP called **everything.jsp** that minifies the JavaScript code. I looked for it in the Github repository and I found this file: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/foundation/frontend-js/frontend-js-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/everything.jsp (but it is empty).

By any chance, someone knows how this **everything.jsp** is invoked? Or how can I guarantee only one version of jQuery is loaded?

Best regards.

Comment: Liferay should have just the 2.x version inside. What version of the portal are you running? Is this happening on a clean theme and on a bare page without any portlets?

Comment: I was using Liferay 7.0 GA2 back then. I will re-test this issue to see if it continues occurring.